# Embed MP3 wont loop

Tags: html

**Hi.**
I have a song, that I would like to have looped, but I cant really figure out what the problem is. Currently it's only playing a single time and then stops with no loop.
The code is as follows

```
<embed name="bosse" src="bosse.mp3" loop="true" autostart="true" style="visibility:hidden;"/>
```

Comment: Try removing the `style="visibility:hidden;"`, does it work without that?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still dosn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [HTML5 Audio control](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp):

```
<audio controls loop autoplay hidden>
  <source src="bosse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

In the first tag, it specifies `loop`, `autoplay`, and `hidden`.  The *`Your browser does not support the audio element.`* part is for if the audio controls is not supported by the browser, however, Firefox, Chrome, IE and Safari, as well as Opera all support this, according to W3Schools.